# How to prevent allure-junit5 from generating reports for Cucumber7 tests?

Tags: java, maven, cucumber, junit5, allure

I have a project with UI tests in Cucumber7 running with JUnit5 and API tests in plain JUnit.

So I need the dependencies `allure-junit5` and `allure-cucumber7-jvm` in order to generate reports for plain JUnit tests and for Cucumber tests. But because the Cucumber tests run with JUnit, their reports are generated by both dependencies and I can get rid of neither because they are essential to generating reports for half of the tests.

Is there a way to prevent `allure-junit5` from generating reports for Cucumber tests? Or maybe a way to merge duplicates?

Here is my pom.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>project</artifactId>
    <version>2.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
        <maven.compiler.source>17</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>17</maven.compiler.target>
        <maven.compiler.plugin.version>3.11.0</maven.compiler.plugin.version>

        <allure-junit5.version>2.21.0</allure-junit5.version>
        <allure-cucumber7-jvm.version>2.21.0</allure-cucumber7-jvm.version>
        <assertj-core.version>3.24.2</assertj-core.version>
        <maven.surefire.plugin.version>3.0.0</maven.surefire.plugin.version>
        <log4j.version>2.20.0</log4j.version>
        <slf4j.version>2.0.7</slf4j.version>

        <rest-assured.version>5.3.0</rest-assured.version>
        <slf4j-log4j12.version>2.0.7</slf4j-log4j12.version>
        <aspectj.version>1.9.19</aspectj.version>
        <jackson.version>2.14.2</jackson.version>
        <lombok.version>1.18.26</lombok.version>

        <selenium.version>4.8.3</selenium.version>
        <webdrivermanager.version>5.3.2</webdrivermanager.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
                <artifactId>cucumber-bom</artifactId>
                <version>7.11.2</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.junit</groupId>
                <artifactId>junit-bom</artifactId>
                <version>5.9.2</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <dependencies>
        <!-- Rest Assured dependency | For API Testing -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.rest-assured</groupId>
            <artifactId>rest-assured</artifactId>
            <version>${rest-assured.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <!--Junit
        Dependencies | For Test execution-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.platform</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-platform-suite</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!--Cucumber
        Dependencies | For Test execution-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-java</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-picocontainer</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-junit-platform-engine</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!--WebDriver
        Dependency | For UI testing-->

        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.github.bonigarcia</groupId>
            <artifactId>webdrivermanager</artifactId>
            <version>${webdrivermanager.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
            <version>${selenium.version}</version>
            <type>pom</type>
        </dependency>
        <!--Allure
        Dependency | For Reporting-->
        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.qameta.allure</groupId>
            <artifactId>allure-cucumber7-jvm</artifactId>
            <version>${allure-cucumber7-jvm.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.qameta.allure</groupId>
            <artifactId>allure-junit5</artifactId>
            <version>${allure-junit5.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.qameta.allure</groupId>
            <artifactId>allure-rest-assured</artifactId>
            <version>${allure-junit5.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.assertj</groupId>
            <artifactId>assertj-core</artifactId>
            <version>${assertj-core.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <!--Log4J
        Dependency | For Logging-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
            <version>${log4j.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>${slf4j.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-simple</artifactId>
            <version>${slf4j.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-annotations</artifactId>
            <version>${jackson.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
            <version>${jackson.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
            <version>${jackson.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <version>${lombok.version}</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${maven.surefire.plugin.version}</version>
                <configuration>
                    <systemProperties>
                        <property>
                           <name>allure.results.directory</name>
                           <value>target/allure-results</value>
                         </property>
                     </systemProperties>
                    <testFailureIgnore>false</testFailureIgnore>
                    <argLine>
                        -javaagent:"${settings.localRepository}/org/aspectj/aspectjweaver/${aspectj.version}/aspectjweaver-${aspectj.version}.jar" -Dcucumber.options="--plugin io.qameta.allure.cucumber5jvm.AllureCucumber5Jvm"
                        -Dcucumber.options="--plugin io.qameta.allure.cucumber7jvm.AllureCucumber7Jvm"
                    </argLine>
                    <systemPropertyVariables>
                        <property>
                            <name>junit.jupiter.extensions.autodetection.enabled</name>
                            <value>true</value>
                        </property>
                    </systemPropertyVariables>
                </configuration>
                <dependencies>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
                        <artifactId>aspectjweaver</artifactId>
                        <version>${aspectj.version}</version>
                    </dependency>
                </dependencies>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>io.qameta.allure</groupId>
                <artifactId>allure-maven</artifactId>
                <version>2.21.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <reportVersion>2.21.0</reportVersion>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>


</project>
```

My RunCucumberTest class :

```
package com.example.ui.web;

import org.junit.platform.suite.api.ConfigurationParameter;
import org.junit.platform.suite.api.IncludeEngines;
import org.junit.platform.suite.api.SelectClasspathResource;
import org.junit.platform.suite.api.Suite;

import static io.cucumber.junit.platform.engine.Constants.PLUGIN_PROPERTY_NAME;
import static io.cucumber.junit.platform.engine.Constants.GLUE_PROPERTY_NAME;
import static io.cucumber.junit.platform.engine.Constants.PLUGIN_PUBLISH_QUIET_PROPERTY_NAME;

@Suite
@IncludeEngines("cucumber")
@SelectClasspathResource("com/example/ui/web")
@ConfigurationParameter(key = PLUGIN_PROPERTY_NAME, value = "pretty,io.qameta.allure.cucumber7jvm.AllureCucumber7Jvm")
@ConfigurationParameter(key = GLUE_PROPERTY_NAME, value = "com.example")
@ConfigurationParameter(key = PLUGIN_PUBLISH_QUIET_PROPERTY_NAME, value = "true")
public class RunCucumberTest {
}
```

And this is what my current reports look like :

[Allure report](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2dEgg.png)

The duplicates are underlined. The bottom ones are generated by `allure-junit5` and are less complete.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Worked around this problem by creating two maven profiles, each only launching either API or UI tests by excluding the others. Also moved allure-junit5 dependency to the API profile so it wouldn't try to generate results for UI tests.

Then I just run the profiles one after the other like this :

```
mvn clean
mvn package -Papi-tests
mvn package -Pui-tests
```

Both profiles generate allure results in the same folder so when I generate the reports all results are used and I get a pretty report for both UI and API with no duplicate. Here is the result :

[image]

and here is the resulting pom.xml :

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>project</artifactId>
    <version>2.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
        <maven.compiler.source>17</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>17</maven.compiler.target>
        <maven.compiler.plugin.version>3.11.0</maven.compiler.plugin.version>

        <allure-junit5.version>2.21.0</allure-junit5.version>
        <allure-cucumber7-jvm.version>2.21.0</allure-cucumber7-jvm.version>
        <assertj-core.version>3.24.2</assertj-core.version>
        <maven.surefire.plugin.version>3.0.0</maven.surefire.plugin.version>
        <log4j.version>2.20.0</log4j.version>
        <slf4j.version>2.0.7</slf4j.version>

        <rest-assured.version>5.3.0</rest-assured.version>
        <slf4j-log4j12.version>2.0.7</slf4j-log4j12.version>
        <aspectj.version>1.9.19</aspectj.version>
        <jackson.version>2.14.2</jackson.version>
        <lombok.version>1.18.26</lombok.version>

        <selenium.version>4.8.3</selenium.version>
        <webdrivermanager.version>5.3.2</webdrivermanager.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
                <artifactId>cucumber-bom</artifactId>
                <version>7.11.2</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.junit</groupId>
                <artifactId>junit-bom</artifactId>
                <version>5.9.2</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <dependencies>
        <!-- Rest Assured dependency | For API Testing -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.rest-assured</groupId>
            <artifactId>rest-assured</artifactId>
            <version>${rest-assured.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <!--Junit
        Dependencies | For Test execution-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.platform</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-platform-suite</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!--Cucumber
        Dependencies | For Test execution-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-java</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-picocontainer</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-junit-platform-engine</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!--WebDriver
        Dependency | For UI testing-->

        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.github.bonigarcia</groupId>
            <artifactId>webdrivermanager</artifactId>
            <version>${webdrivermanager.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
            <version>${selenium.version}</version>
            <type>pom</type>
        </dependency>
        <!--Allure
        Dependency | For Reporting-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.qameta.allure</groupId>
            <artifactId>allure-cucumber7-jvm</artifactId>
            <version>${allure-cucumber7-jvm.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.qameta.allure</groupId>
            <artifactId>allure-rest-assured</artifactId>
            <version>${allure-junit5.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.assertj</groupId>
            <artifactId>assertj-core</artifactId>
            <version>${assertj-core.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <!--Log4J
        Dependency | For Logging-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
            <version>${log4j.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>${slf4j.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-simple</artifactId>
            <version>${slf4j.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-annotations</artifactId>
            <version>${jackson.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
            <version>${jackson.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
            <version>${jackson.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <version>${lombok.version}</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <profiles>
        <profile>
            <id>ui-tests</id>
            <build>
                <plugins>
                    <!-- display active profile in compile phase -->
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                        <artifactId>maven-help-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>3.4.0</version>
                        <executions>
                            <execution>
                                <id>show-profiles</id>
                                <phase>compile</phase>
                                <goals>
                                    <goal>active-profiles</goal>
                                </goals>
                            </execution>
                        </executions>
                    </plugin>
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                        <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>${maven.surefire.plugin.version}</version>
                        <configuration>
                            <excludes>
                                <exclude>**/payment/zppapi/*.java</exclude>
                            </excludes>
                            <systemProperties>
                                <property>
                                    <name>allure.results.directory</name>
                                    <value>target/allure-results</value>
                                </property>
                            </systemProperties>
                            <testFailureIgnore>false</testFailureIgnore>
                            <argLine>
                                -javaagent:"${settings.localRepository}/org/aspectj/aspectjweaver/${aspectj.version}/aspectjweaver-${aspectj.version}.jar"
                                -Dcucumber.options="--plugin
                                io.qameta.allure.cucumber7jvm.AllureCucumber7Jvm"
                            </argLine>
                        </configuration>
                        <dependencies>
                            <dependency>
                                <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
                                <artifactId>aspectjweaver</artifactId>
                                <version>${aspectj.version}</version>
                            </dependency>
                        </dependencies>
                    </plugin>
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>io.qameta.allure</groupId>
                        <artifactId>allure-maven</artifactId>
                        <version>2.21.0</version>
                        <configuration>
                            <reportVersion>2.21.0</reportVersion>
                        </configuration>
                    </plugin>
                </plugins>
            </build>
        </profile>
        <profile>
            <id>api-tests</id>
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>io.qameta.allure</groupId>
                    <artifactId>allure-junit5</artifactId>
                    <version>${allure-junit5.version}</version>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
            <build>
                <plugins>
                    <!-- display active profile in compile phase -->
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                        <artifactId>maven-help-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>3.4.0</version>
                        <executions>
                            <execution>
                                <id>show-profiles</id>
                                <phase>compile</phase>
                                <goals>
                                    <goal>active-profiles</goal>
                                </goals>
                            </execution>
                        </executions>
                    </plugin>
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                        <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>${maven.surefire.plugin.version}</version>
                        <configuration>
                            <excludes>
                                <exclude>**/RunCucumberTest.java</exclude>
                            </excludes>
                            <systemProperties>
                                <property>
                                    <name>allure.results.directory</name>
                                    <value>target/allure-results</value>
                                </property>
                            </systemProperties>
                            <testFailureIgnore>false</testFailureIgnore>
                            <argLine>
                                -javaagent:"${settings.localRepository}/org/aspectj/aspectjweaver/${aspectj.version}/aspectjweaver-${aspectj.version}.jar"
                            </argLine>
                        </configuration>
                        <dependencies>
                            <dependency>
                                <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
                                <artifactId>aspectjweaver</artifactId>
                                <version>${aspectj.version}</version>
                            </dependency>
                        </dependencies>
                    </plugin>
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>io.qameta.allure</groupId>
                        <artifactId>allure-maven</artifactId>
                        <version>2.21.0</version>
                        <configuration>
                            <reportVersion>2.21.0</reportVersion>
                        </configuration>
                    </plugin>
                </plugins>
            </build>
        </profile>
    </profiles>

</project>
```

Please note that I am very new to maven so my pom.xml can probably be improved.